# Generating Outlook Crash Dumps

Tags: outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin, dump, crash-dumps

I would like to know if it is possible for Outlook to generate a crash dump when a crash happens within my Outlook COM addin - so I can debug it if it happen at a customer's site.

For simplicity - I inserted a division by 0 upon the OnOpen event which causes the application to crash every time, however Outlook does not generate a dump for this.

Does anyone know how to generate such crash dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this problem:

In the registry under:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
```

Set the `ForceQueue` to 1.

Than under:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue
```

You will find your crash dump.